# remove does not work with carrierwave_backgrounder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, carrierwave

When I use carrierwave_backgrounder to render videos with delayed_job, I cannot remove the video by seeting parameter :remove_video.

:remove_video is included in attr_accessible.

I use store_in_background in the model.

Removing of the video does work, if I comment out the "store_in_background"

How can I remove the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to proccess the deletion in foreground by adding in the contoller#update:

```
@model.process_video_upload = true if params[:model][:remove_video] == 1
```